# Is there any way to have end to end type safety in a website with React and Typescript as the frontend and Django as the backend?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, typescript, next.js

I want to build a website with NextJS as the frontend and Django as the backend. I wanted to know if there was any way to ensure client to server type safety in my stack.

Although I have searched for many libraries, but there doesn't seem to be any. The closest library I found was mypy, which ensured type safety in the backend, but not between the server and the client like tRPC.

Comment: You could probably make a tool that looks for controllers (or whatever the Django equivalent would be) and auto-generate the appropriate typescript api client that would implement the front end portion of those controller methods

Comment: Define "ensure". Generally you can have e.g. a json schema defined or e.g. and openapi spec and then generate the types for client and server based on that.